# How to create Discord Bot slash command with several options

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently programming a Discord DnD bot.

I want to make a slash command with autocomplete, but it does not work the way I want.

How the command should be: /spells [classname] <- Output: an embedded list.

```py
@bot.slash_command(description="Spell List")
async def spells(ctx, name=["warlock,", "wizard", "bard"] ):
    # Erstellen des Embeds
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Spell-Liste {name}", color=discord.Color.red())
    
    for level, spells in warlock_spells_data.items():
        spell_list = '\n'.join(spells)
        embed.add_field(name=level, value=spell_list, inline=False)

    # Nachricht mit Embed senden
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If it helps more, here's the Github link to all the code:
https://github.com/HolyCodez/dnd-discord-bot

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for using [autocomplete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.autocomplete)?

Comment: Yes, but i didn't understand the documentation.